# C# button text and resize

Tags: c#

I have a simple button that when clicked should change the text from Help to Hide and the windows form size.  The problem i'm having is it cant find the if statement.  It cant see the button3.text Help or hide.  Any tips or suggestions?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string helpstring = "Help";
        string hidestring = "Hide";
        if (button3.Text == helpstring)
        {
            button3.Text = hidestring;
            Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1106, 563);
        }
        if (button3.Text == "Hide")
        {
            Size = new System.Drawing.Size(586, 563);
            button3.Text = helpstring;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just an observation, you're trying to change a button you've called button3 and your handler method is named button2_Click. You haven't accidently written the handler for the wrong button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have your buttons wrong.

The handler is named button**2**_Click, but the code accesses button**3**.
This is why you should **always** name your controls.

Your problem might be that the button**3** is starting out with a `Text` that is neither `Help` nor `Hide`.  Therefore, neither `if` statement will do anything.

You should set a breakpoint in the function (click the bar on the left next to one of your lines of code), then move the mouse over `button3.Text` and see what it's actually equal to.

However, if the button's text is `Help`, nothing will happen.  As [manitra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006783/c-button-text-and-resize/2006808#2006808) pointed out, you don't have an `else` clause.

Therefore, your code will see that the button's text is `Help`, and change it to `Hide`.
However, the next `if` statement will see that the button's text is now `Hide`, and will change it back to `Help`.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot an "else". This should work :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string helpstring = "Help";
    string hidestring = "Hide";
    if (button3.Text == helpstring)
    {
        button3.Text = hidestring;
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1106, 563);
    }
    else if (button3.Text == "Hide") //this is where you should put an else
    {
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(586, 563);
        button3.Text = helpstring;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you debug this method (without the "else"), the execution will enter in both "if" statemeent thats why it looks like nothing happens. In fact, the text is changed to "hide" but is immediatly changed back to "Help".

Answer (score 2):

You have two ifs in parallel. The first block will execute, changing the button text to "Hide". Then, the second will also execute, changing the text back to "Help".

Use an else block instead.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set a breakpoint at the start of the method and see what the value is for button3.Text?

My guess is that your event is not wired up properly and the code is not even being exectued.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an ampersand in the text of the button (e.g. &Help or &Hide) so that users can use the keyboard shortcut?  If so, the text property will not be equal.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems with this code.

First things first though, make sure that your button's click event is properly hooked to the `button2_Click` handler, as there seems to be some disparity between the name of the method, and the objects referenced within the method. The naming on these should be fixed either way for readability's sake.

Second, your code uses two `if` statements, rather than an `if...else` statement. If the first condition in your code is true, then the code inside the first `if` will cause the condition in the second `if` to be true, thus reverting everything to it's original condition.

Your code SHOULD read (including renaming your method):

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string helpstring = "Help";
    string hidestring = "Hide";
    if (button3.Text == helpstring)
    {
        button3.Text = hidestring;
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1106, 563);
    }
    else
    {
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(586, 563);
        button3.Text = helpstring;
    }
}
```

NOTE: There is no need for a second `if` if these are the only two possible conditions, a simple `else` will improve performance and achieve the desired effect.